# How to insert a xml element from another namespace as a child and still be a valid xml?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following xml file

```
<Layout xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Layout/">
  <Numeric Id="temperature" Caption="Temperature">
    <validation:IsValidWhen xmlns:validation="http://tempuri.org/Validation/">

    </validation:IsValidWhen>
  </Numeric>
</Layout>
```

The `http://tempuri.org/Layout/` XSD does not have a reference to `http://tempuri.org/Validation/` and I cannot change it.

I am getting the error

```
The element 'Numeric' in namespace 'http://tempuri.org/Layout/' has invalid child element 'IsValidWhen' in namespace 'http://tempuri.org/Validation/'. List of possible elements expected: 'ContextMenu, OnChanged, OnLeave' in namespace 'http://tempuri.org/Layout/'
```

How can I make this XML be valid when the parent element is from a schema that is not aware of my validation schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not control the `http://tempuri.org/Layout/` schema, then there may not be anything you can do to make this "valid."  However, it's still perfectly reasonable and well-formed XML that can be used by any party that knows what to expect.  If the other parties you're interacting with understand the format, there really isn't any problem.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I could try to make the Actipro SyntaxEditor to ignore those errors if that still make it a valid Xml.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use [XML catalogs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Catalog) to instruct your tools (or code, which has strict validation) where to locate multiple unrelated schemas.